# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting - sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Python 3.7.3

I cannot format output of result function. For example, if you just only use `print result`, you will see all data of come back. If you use a loop to get all types of values to identifying is or not strings values:

```
for i in result:
    print(type(result))
```

You will see all values as str:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

I've tried to print each number of position of a tuple but It's does not work. I get this error when I trying do it:

```
print(Messages.issue_found + "ID : %s o %s" % result[0], result[1])


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sincorchetes/Projects/PyArea/sqlite/run.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(Messages.issue_found + "ID : %s o %s" % result[0], result[1])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

This is code:

Ops.py

```
import sqlite

def search_a_object(type_request):
        conn = connection()
        run = conn.cursor()
        try:
                type_request = (type_request,)
                query = run.execute('SELECT * FROM Object WHERE id=?', type_request)
                get_results = query.fetchone()
                if get_results is None:
                       print("Sorry, This object was not found")
                else:
                        #print(get_results)
                        return get_results
        except:
                print("Sorry, something was wrong :(")
```

run.py

```
import ops as Ops
import msg as Messages
request_id = input(Messages.get_request_id)
        if (request_id is not None and request_id):
            result = Ops.search_a_object(request_id)
            print(Messages.issue_found + "ID : %s o %s" % result)
#   I have problems with this line formatting ^
        else:
            print(Messages.need_more_data)
```

If I use code as up I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sincorchetes/Projects/PyArea/sqlite/run.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(Messages.issue_found + "ID : %s o %s" % result)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Although all values are strings inside tuple.

Comment: Try `print(Messages.issue_found + "ID : %s o %s" % (result[0], result[1]))`

Comment: Thanks! just work. Do you know what happend this? (just to learn)

Comment: The `%` for string formatting expects a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
print(Messages.issue_found + "ID : %s o %s" % (result[0], result[1]))
```

or

```
print( "ID : {} o {}".format(result[0], result[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's solved with this. Could you explain what happend this (if you want)? Just for understand.

Comment: @sincorchetes Could you accept this answer if this is helpful?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forget check it.